# When do you get 10 points for capturing a flag in Conquest?

Tags: battlefield-4

When I take a flag in a game of Conquest in Battlefield 4, I *sometimes* get 10 points every second while taking the flag, but after a short time I stop getting those points while the flag is still not taken.

What are the conditions to get these points? Are there certain timers or amounts that stop them from being awarded, and if so, what are they?

Comment: I assume there's just some internal cooldown on how many such points you can get to avoid people farming points that way.

Comment: @Mario Do you know the conditions? To me it seems to stop at rather random numbers. It also seems unnecessary to me to stop people from farming those points because then they wouldn't need to award them in the first place and you still get the 250 capturing points anyway. So you can still "farm" by taking flags.

Comment: No idea, but it might be an incentive to try to capture different points, i.e. it's more effective to try to capture all x capture points rather than concentrating on a single one (ignoring ticket degradation etc.).